# prompt and change background color in a loop with native javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I would like to write a simply Java script (native) program which MUST use a while loop and do the following.

- prompts user to enter a colour -
- Then change the background to that colour.
- keep prompting them to enter colour and keep changing the background colour until user does not enter anything in the prompt at which point the WHILE loop ends.

I have seen lot of variations of this tackled by using functions - but I want to achieve this only using WHILE loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop until value of the prompt entered is null. However you won't see the color change until after you leave the loop because the command `prompt` is blocking.

```js
while (true) {
  var color = prompt("enter color", "red");
  if (color === null) {
    break;
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

This "asynchronous" version allows the browser to paint between `prompt` to another. But no `while` here.

```js
function prompt_then(then) {
  var color = prompt("enter color", "red");
  if (color === null) {
    return;
  }
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  window.setTimeout(then, 1);
}

prompt_then(prompt_then);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but, how come your first answer works eventhough it uses while loop?

Comment: @lollah mullah, `prompt` blocks the execution. The loop `while` is suspended until the function `prompt` returns a value. That happens when you click the "OK" button.

Comment: `while` loop is ok to use. It's just like `for` loop. Just don't make it endless because browser can't paint or respond when executing loops. If you need a non-blocking loop, you will need to use some sort of "out of loop" process using command like `setTimeout` .  Which the other example explains

Comment: yes @ITgoldman. I understand the difference between the two example. but my question is how come the first example with the while loop works.

Comment: if I explain my understanding of execution,  since the condition for while is true, it goes inside the loop, get the colour, checks if it is null, it is not. so changes the colour and loops, since no delay and the loop starts, how does browser has time to change the colour?

Comment: btw, when I copy past this example on to a file on my local file system (inject into HTML) and open on browser, it does not work

Comment: Oh I understand, I have chrome browser where it doesn't paint. Freezing the browser is not recommended either way. Read more about the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: ok, so there is no way to get this to work, just by using while loop in Chrome?  also why does the script work only on Firefox?